# C# - ASP.NET - Let the user pick a path

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, filepath

I just finished my VisualWebpart which reads some Data from a Oracle Database and writes it into a PDF file which will, at the moment, always be saved in a fix Path I pass as a string. Since this is really static, I'd like to let the user choose the path to save the file.
However I only need the path as a String, so I can put it into the Save-Option of the PDF generator.

Thank you for your Help

Comment: why are you saving the document as a file? do you need it for later? if not, simple send the document as a stream to the user and he/she will see the *Save As* dialog box, no matter what OS they are using...

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET and building the PDF on the server it's not a good idea to ask the user for a path, if its for saving in the client machine then yes, @balexandre answer is right, write it on the output stream and let the user choose where to save it.

Comment: Well I'm using the tool PDFSharp, so I get the Document in the "PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument". Since I really never worked with that before, may someone explain the whole process a little more detailed? Thank you for the fast answers.